# Executes the @PostConstruct method of a stateful session bean not in a transaction (in a Arquillian test)?

Tags: jakarta-ee

I have a stateless session bean,

```
@Stateless
public class MyService {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        Language  language=new Language();
        language.setName("Foo");
        entityManager.persist(language);
    }
    ...
```

In a Arquillian test I have a `CDI` bean (`@RequestScoped` bean), which `@Injects` this service. This test runs OK.

But when I change this bean to a `@Stateful` bean, I get error messages:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: WFLYJPA0060: Transaction is required to perform this operation (either use a transaction or extended persistence context)
    at service.MyServiceTest.testStateful(MyServiceTest.java:71)
```

When I put a `@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)` annotation on the `@PostConstruct` method, the test runs OK. But this is not what I want to do.

Also, I can remove the `@Postconstruct` from the init method, and call the `init` method explicitly in the Arquillian test. Then the `init` method is in a transaction.

So runs the `@PostConstruct` method of a stateful session beans not in a transaction, and of a stateless bean it does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EJB 3.2 Core Contracts and Requirements Specification states the following in §8.3.7:

> For a stateful session bean’s PostConstruct, PreDestroy, PrePassivate or PostActivate lifecycle callback interceptor methods, only the REQUIRES_NEW and NOT_SUPPORTED transaction attributes may be used.

So you can only have either a brand new transaction, or none at all.

If you're trying to get around this then you're not emulating your runtime environment.

Comment: So a `@PostConstruct` method does not execute in a CMT transaction, as a "normal" method does (a method without a `@PostConstruct`, etc annotation?

Comment: For `@Stateful` beans, yes. Remember that they have a much more elaborate lifecycle than `@Stateless` beans.